# Logstash grok pattern for WSO2 log message

Tags: regex, wso2, expression, logstash-grok, wso2-esb

I am currently working with Logstash. I want to parse WSO2 ESB log statement using grok. I have tried different patterns but didn't succeed. Can anyone help me out to write custom pattern for WSO2 ESb log statement.

Here is the sample log message:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-02-25 12:35:18,719]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 131 sec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following Grok Pattern

`TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:tenant_id}\]%{SPACE}\[%{WORD:server_type}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:java_class}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}`

You can use the online "[Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)" application to test grok patterns.

I was writing a blog post on this last few days (What a coincidence? :D). I just published it! See: [Monitor WSO2 Carbon logs with Logstash](http://isuru-perera.blogspot.com/2015/02/monitor-wso2-carbon-logs-with-logstash.html)

Comment: Great. Thanks for your response. I will test and let u know.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer. I'm glad that I could help with the grok pattern! :)